# Disadvantages of including a page which uses jquery into iframe?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I'm working on an asp.net web application and I'm making use of jQuery. The client told me that he wanted to use this web application inside of an iframe in their current webpage.

So basically:

- Is is conventional to inlude a page which uses a lot jQuery (or any other javascript functions) into an iframe?
- Should I expect any difficulties?

I'm asking this because it's not necessary to use jQuery. If this would come up with difficulties, I can simply scrape the jQuery part out of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to do this, would be if the page you'd load in the iframe would be served on a *different domain* than the "outer page", since this could then work as a work-around for the browser's [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) blocks.

**However...** When your client requests something to be used "inside of an iframe in their current application", make sure that they know what they're talking about. It might be that they simply learned the word "iframe" somewhere (and sometime, probably ten years ago...) and want to seem like they know more about what they want than they actually do.

Ask again, and make sure you understand what the client *actually* wants to accomplish - do you need jQuery? Do you need an iframe? What is the *real need* that you should satisfy, and what is the best way to do it (regardless of what your client knows about the internet)?

<sub>Sidenote: these are the kinds of questions that will make your clients recommend you to other potential customers.</sub>

Comment: jQuery isn't needed as stated in the last sentence of my question. But it will make things easier and more fascinating. The web part I'm working on needs to be loaded into an existing webpage from another domain.

Comment: @memetolsen: Then go ahead - build something awesome! As long as whatever you're containing in your iframe is isolated from the rest of your client's web site, you should be able to get everything working with no more problems than what you'd expect in any other web application. (If it's not isolated, I again have to question the choice of using an iframe...)